# How to put all the file names into an array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, path, filenames, subdirectory

I plan to list all the file names of a current folder (include subfolder) and put them and their path into an array. I can use s=dir to put the names and path of all the files in the current folder, I can also use "dir **/*.*" to show the files in the current folder and subfolders.

But when I use "s=dir **/*.*", Matlab gives me error and I am not able to proceed. Is there anyone can help me on this？

The reason why I want to do this is to compare two folders which may contain plenty of duplicate files. I want to use file name as the indicator and to find out the new adding or removed files, so that I can update the log excel we have.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list only the files and not the directories try

```
file_names = dir('**/');
file_names = file_names(~[file_names.isdir]);
file_names = {file_names.name}
```

Comment: Great, Thank you. Alex bGoode. May I ask where can I check the extra commands here (like .isdir) so that I can check myself?

Comment: You can find this information either in matlab's documentation [dir](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) or by inspecting the return value in your workspace.

Comment: Hi, Alex bGoode: Sorry, I have a followup question. It seems the command dir('**/') works in R2017b. And it doesn't work in R2015a. If I want to get the same results using R2015a (all file names and paths in current folder and subfolders) in R2015a, is there any command can help me do this?

Comment: I dont't have this matlab version, but the dir command should be available 'Introduced before R2006a'. Maybe try dir('**/*')?

Answer (score 0):

You were really close, you can just run:

```
s = dir('**\');
```

And that should get you what you need

Comment: Hi, acampb311, may I have a followup question? I saw plenty of "." or ".." or subfolders shown after conducting this command. May I ask if there is a way to only show files without the folders and these "." and ".."? Thank you.